# Video playback that smooths speech at high speeds

Tags: video, video-editing, media-player, vlc

I like to watch lectures on high speed (usually between 1.5x and 2x) with VLC. The limiting factor is often the rate at which the speech becomes unintelligibly clipped/choppy.  Is there software that smooths out audio of human language in a way that allows for higher playback speed?

To be clear: I'm looking for something that intelligently modifies the audio beyond just a uniform speed up, e.g. compressing the pauses between words while stretching out the words themselves, or making consonant sounds "crisper", etc.

(I am interested in any operating system, but ideally this would be for OSX. Even more ideal would be a VLC plugin.)

Comment: Overcast is a podcast (audio, no video) player for iOS that apparently cuts out pauses in conversations: https://overcast.fm/

Comment: [PocketCast](http://www.shiftyjelly.com/pocketcasts) clips silences, but unfortunately it isn't very aggressive about it, probably because it would tend to mangle things unless done carefully.  (I suspect it would require a lot more software sophistication with human speech to appreciably change the average playback speed.)  It cut out less than a second over the first few minutes of a conversation I used as an example, so it essentially does nothing.

Comment: You could try uploading it to Youtube as a private video and use their player at higher speeds: https://www.quora.com/Is-there-a-way-of-watching-YouTube-videos-at-higher-than-2x-speed

Comment: Is YouTube editing the audio to make it more intelligible? As stated in the post, I am not just looking for a way to uniformly speed up the playback.

Comment: I don't know. There's also Audio Anchor (https://f-droid.org/en/packages/com.prangesoftwaresolutions.audioanchor/) that does a very good job of fast playback. Sorry for the late reply! Hope it helps!

Comment: My new related question: https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/85183/android-app-for-playing-audio-files-at-high-speed