# What's the best software for smooth video playback at high speeds?

Tags: video, youtube, vlc, mooc

I've found when playing a video lecture back at fast speeds that the limiting factor is often intelligibility due to "clipping" or skipping of the sound, rather than it just being too fast.  Surprisingly, this is *worse* using the default VLC playback-speed controls than if I watch the identical video file on YouTube at the identical speed.

**What piece of standalone software produces the smoothest sound when playing back video with human speech at high speed?**

(I am interested in any desktop software that out-performs VLC on any desktop platform, but for reference I have a mid-2014 MacBook Pro (Retina, 13-inch) running macOS 10.13.4.  Free software preferred but paying is OK.)

Comment: Please note that this is distinct from my [other question](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/27175/video-playback-that-smooths-speech-at-high-speeds) asking for recommendation of software that actively *modifies* the video/audio to remove pauses or otherwise make the speech more intelligible.  Here I am just asking about smooth speed up.

Comment: My new related question: https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/85183/android-app-for-playing-audio-files-at-high-speed

Answer (score 1):

[This person is saying](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1630569#c10) that they liked the Firefox (Gecko)'s algorithm the most, even compared to VLC.